# How to use URL parameters for filtering share point view

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, list-view, view

I'm using SharePoint 2013. Can anyone please suggest me how to use URL parameters in SharePoint 2013 view for filtering view results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter a list via URL Parameter by using `Query string (URL) filter web part`

**Steps :**

- Edit your page that has the list view
- Add Query string (URL) filter web part.

[image]

- Click on Open the tool pane to configure the Filter web part.
- Set the Query String Parameter Name to your URL Parameter Name.
- Edit `Query string (URL) filter` web part > Select Connection > Select Send Filter Values To > Select your List to view result.
- At Choose connection Tab > Connection type > Select Get Filter Values From.
- At Configure Connection > Select your Filter field.

For more details check [Filter a List via URL Parameter in SharePoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/10/28/open-filter-list-url-modal-dialog-sharepoint/)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit old, but it does seem to (mostly) still work:

ListURL.aspx?FilterField1=column&FilterValue1=value

See http://sharepointificate.blogspot.com/2012/12/filtering-listviews-with-url-query.html for a bit more info.

I've had trouble using it with Boolean columns, but other than that, it seems to work OK.